# The closed orientable surface of genus 2

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a very simple question to ask.  What is a closed orientable surface of genus 2?

Comment: Like [this](http://www.chicoparty.com/Productimages/QN1008B%20BLUE%208%20MEGALOON.jpg)

Comment: Agenus 1 surface would be like a normal (i.e. circular) swimming ring, a genus 2 surface is a swimming ring having the shape of a figure eight.

Comment: Are you asking what the words "closed", "orientable", "surface", and "genus" mean or are you asking what this particular surface looks like?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-2_surface

Comment: So is it a two holed torus?

Comment: @caley: Yes, it is sometimes called a $2$-holed torus.

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question is answered, the surface you are describing looks like this:

[image: double torus]

It is referred to by the following names: double torus, $2$-holed torus, $\mathbb{T}^2 \# \mathbb{T}^2$, or ["a sphere with two handles"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleTorus.html).